# Huawei E303 12d1:14fe switch to ethernet mode

Tags: linux, drivers, 3g

I'm using the Huawei E303 3G dongle with many Raspberry Pi3s. Apparently there are several and different E303 models (no difference in the product label, just the shell color).

I have two of them; the first appears as `12d1:1f01` in `lsusb` output. I can successfully switch the dongle to ethernet mode using this command: `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1f01 -V 0x12d1 -P 0x14dc -M "55534243123456780000000000000a11062000000000000100000000000000"`

The other dongle appears as `12d1:14fe` and I don't know what MessageContent to set to do the switch. I managed to switch to `12d1:1c05` that seems to be another disk mode, to `12d1:1506` that is broadband modem mode, and to `12d1:1001` that is ???

Any help would be great

**EDIT 1:**

Following dirkt indications I took a look at configPack.tar.gz and found this:

```
cat 12d1\:1f01
# Huawei E353 (3.se) and others
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProductList="14db,14dc"
HuaweiNewMode=1
NoDriverLoading=1

cat 12d1\:14fe
# T-Mobile NL (Huawei E352)
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProductList="1506,150f,151d"
HuaweiNewMode=1
```

Could the `NoDriverLoading=1` be the catch?

**EDIT 2:**

This command `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0xXXXX -J` switches automatically the first dongle to ethernet mode, and the second one to broadband modem mode (-J parameter does the trick).

My problem still remains: I cannot set the second dongle to ethernet mode

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

There's a database for usb_modeswitch; on Debian it's in the package `usb-modeswitch-data`. It contains the file `configPack.tar.gz`, which you can unpack in a temporary directory to find out what's already known about specific devices. In your case, one finds:

```
$ cat 12d1\:1f01 
# Huawei E353 (3.se) and others
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProductList="14db,14dc"
HuaweiNewMode=1

$ cat 12d1\:14fe 
# Huawei E352 (T-Mobile NL), E173s (Variant)
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProductList="1506,150f,151d,1c1e"
HuaweiNewMode=1
```

So you can switch the second dongle (at least) to the listed four devices. I don't know how you managed to switch to `1001` and `1c05`; if you can do that reliably, please contact the [project maintainer](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#contrib), tell him how you managed to do it, and have him include it in the database.

The database entries don't contain MessageContent strings, but a switching mode decription, so my guess is you can switch using that procedure without providing a MessageContent with `-M` on the command line (for both dongles).

Please test if that works, switch to all four modes of the second dongle, and see as what kind of device they appear.

**Edit**: Looked at the source. The ChangeLog says

```
Version 2.2.0, 2014/05/29
  Introduction of parameter "HuaweiNewMode", wrapping the standard bulk
  message for all newer Huawei devices; support for generic fall-back
  config files, combined with OS switch (per vendor ID), implementation
  to use a specific switching command on Android for all Huawei devices
  (see README of data package for details); this change was suggested
  by Huawei
```

And the README in usb-modeswitch-data says:

> For Huawei devices, the switching method is uniform and not likely to change,
>   so it is possible to provide a generic configuration.

So it's nearly certain you don't need to specify MessageContent (and it's possible ignored even if you specify it).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How can I switch mode without setting a MessageContent? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry for double-comment. I did a try, please take a look at the OP

Comment: Just leave out the `-M "blah"` part. Try for both dongles, that will show if `NoDriverLoading=1` makes a difference (but I doubt it). As I said, I don't know if it will work - I don't have the hardware to test. If it doesn't work, we'll have to figure out the format of the MessageContent string for Huawei, which might need some googling and source reading.

Comment: If I run `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1f01` or `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x14fe` nothing changes

Comment: If I say "leave out the `-M "blah"` part", then of course you still need to provide the target vendor/product id (`-V` and `-P`). Without giving those, obviously usb_modeswitch won't do anything. I also edited the answer concerning necessity of MessageContent.

Comment: You're right, my fault. See edit 2 please

Comment: Again: If you don't provide the **target** vendor/product id, then usb_modeswitch won't know what device to switch it to. Try `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x14fe -V 0x12d1 -P 0x1506`, then `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x14fe -V 0x12d1 -P 0x150f`, then `... -P 0x151d`, then `-P 0x1c1e`. Add `-J` if necessary. That should switch it into 4 different modes (whatever they are).

Comment: Without -J the end of output says "Warning: no switching method given. See documentation"; adding -J seems to ignore the target vid/pid as I always get the dongle into 1506